# Where are the field variables in a block template?

Tags: theming, blocks

How can I access the variables of the fields in a block template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're in the `content` variable, e.g.

```
<div{{ attributes }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if label %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  {% block content %}
    {{ content.field_foo }}
    {{ content|without('field_bar') }}
    {{ content.field_bar }}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

For reference, these are the default core variables you have available (from the [core template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21templates%21block.html.twig/8.4.x):

> - plugin_id: The ID of the block implementation.
> - label: The configured label of the block if visible.
> - configuration: A list of the block's configuration values.
> - label: The configured label for the block.
> - label_display: The display settings for the label.
> - provider: The module or other provider that provided this block plugin.
> - Block plugin specific settings will also be stored here.
> - content: The content of this block.
> - attributes: array of HTML attributes populated by modules, intended to be added to the main container tag of this template.
> - id: A valid HTML ID and guaranteed unique.
> - title_attributes: Same as attributes, except applied to the main title tag that appears in the template.
> - title_prefix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be displayed in front of the main title tag that appears in the template.
> - title_suffix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be displayed after the main title tag that appears in the template.